# Override the style sheet of a dependency in a maven project

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, overriding, ff4j

I have a dependency in a maven project which renders html pages. I want to change the style of a table since the view is getting cut off. How can I access the stylesheet of the table and inject rules into it? Using intellij as the IDE and the dependency is the FF4J package.

Comment: Please show the pom file and what kind of dependency produces a HTML page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS you are looking for is part of the dependency `ff4j-web` and the static HTML content is located in [Github Repository](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j/tree/master/ff4j-web/src/main/resources). This solution has been chosen to have a working web application inside a JAR with no internet required (back in 2013)

Unfortunately, to change this content you will have update the source code

- Fork the repository on your account
- `mvn clean install` to check everything is OK (you may want to skip the 10k+ tests with `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` it should work but takes 12min)
- Change version of dependency in your own project from 1.7.2 to 1.8-SNAPSHOT
- Edit the [CSS](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j/blob/master/ff4j-web/src/main/resources/static/css/style.css) according to your findings and clean install ff4j-web.
- Create a pull request to have everyone benefit of your changes

If you know what is missing in the CSS you can also update the issue [existing one](https://github.com/ff4j/ff4j/issues/316) adn we will be pleased to release 1.7.3 with your updates.

Comment: Adding this to style.css works: table td { word-break: break-all; } It's not pretty but it gets the job done.